# Jquery Ajax - How to display data table when select three rows of three tables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table, datatable

I have loaded data into a table with each table being a different SQL database. Now I want to click on each table 1 row. After clicking on 3 rows of 3 tables will display the data of another data table.
My form table  with 3 other html table(1 normal and 2 check box table) :
[image]

My data table i want load it form SQL.
[image]

All three tables Form 1 Form2 Form 3 have a VoyageKey field, based on that to load the other data table

I have tried assigning click event for each select to 1 row and for the 3rd time it will call ajax to load the data table with no success.

When I select 3 tables. It will load another datatable similar to this, and they are not from the same database but as separate tables.[image]
[image]

based on VoyageKey of Form 1 to display datatable after selecting rows of 3 tables
[image]

[image]

I want after 3 click events to display the datatable, but the data displayed depends on the SQL VoyageKey field
My code Ajax load datatable :

```
  $('body').on('click', 'tr', function () {
  var vesselName = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
  var groupvoyage = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text();

  console.log('vesselName:', vesselName);
  console.log('voyagekey:', voyagekey);
  // Gán giá trị cho trường input
  $('#chooseVessel').val(vesselName);
  $('#chooseVoyage').val(groupvoyage);

  let me = $(this);
  // select me
  me.toggleClass('selected');
  // deselect other tr:s in the same table
  me.parent().find('.selected').not(me).removeClass('selected');
  // if three rows are selected, then do something
  // (there can only be one row in each table that is selected)
  if ($('.selected').length === 3) {

// Gọi ajax để load dữ liệu dựa trên voyagekey
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/Tally/Tally/get',
  data: { voyagekey: voyagekey },
success: function(result) {
 // Xử lý dữ liệu nhận được và hiển thị lên bảng ContentTable
      table.clear().draw();
      table.clear().rows.add(result.data).draw();


},
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
});
        }
      });
```

But Form 2 and Form 3 in my table is checkbox. How to adjust. Also when loading ajax I want to rely on the VoyageKey field coincides with Form 1 to load correctly.

When I click on the data table it is hidden. How to edit and manipulate the board

Help me!

Comment: "_I have tried assigning click event for each select to 1 row and for the 3rd time it will call ajax to load the data table with no success._" -  OK - but what is your _specific_ problem? Where are _specifically_ getting stuck? It seems to me that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76169343/12567365) provided by @thomasfrank does exactly what you need. It detects when all 3 selections have been made: `if ($('.selected').length === 3) { ... }`. And that triggers an action (a message) - but that action could be to initialize your 4th table, instead.

Comment: If your problem is how to "_call ajax to load the data table_", then show us what you tried. Show us your code. Don't just say "no success". Also, you can research [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=load+datatable+from+button+click+site:stackoverflow.com). In those questions the event is a button click - but that part of the solution is not relevant for you. You already have the "event" you need.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my problem to make it easier to understand. I want to call ajax after having selected 3 click events and rely on the VoyageKey field to display the appropriate data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this, make sure only one row can be selected at once in each table (I'm using the class name **selected** for the selected row.)

That means when we have three elements with the class **selected** they must be in different tables, so then do something.

Also see the comments in the code.

```js
// create dummy tables
function createDummyTables() {
  $('body').html([
    ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
    ['rabbit', 'dog', 'cat'],
    ['house', 'apartment', 'tent']
  ].map(x => '<table>' + x.map(x =>
    `<tr><td>${x}</td></tr>`).join('') + '</table>').join(''));
}
createDummyTables();

$('body').on('click', 'tr', function () {
  let me = $(this);
  // select me
  me.toggleClass('selected');
  // deselect other tr:s in the same  table
  me.parent().find('.selected').not(me).removeClass('selected');
  // if three rows are selected, then do something
  // (there can only be one row in each table that is selected)
  if ($('.selected').length === 3) {
    let [color, pet, housing] =
      [...$('.selected')].map(x => x.innerText);
    let message = `Going to fetch a ${color} ${pet} `
      + `that can live in your ${housing} with you!`;
    alert(message);
    // maybe deselect all after we have done something
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #a8bfe1;
}

tr.selected {
  background-color: #7f97ba;
}

td {
  font-family: Verdana;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Three tables</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. But one table is one other database.
I want after clicking 3 tables as you instructed to load another data table as above

Comment: I can't help you with how you fetch your data unless you know  the route in your REST-api (or similar) corresponding to the correct table in the correct  db. And tell me the route. Do you know this route?

Comment: I have loaded data from database of 3 tables on form table. Now I only need after selecting 3 to display another data table to load. I declared database and wrote in controllers to call it.

Comment: Do you mean that you alread have all the data loaded? I am confused... So you don't want to fetch more data after the user makes his choices? What do you need help with then - replacing the view with a new table?

Comment: That's hard to understand in English ;)

Comment: Sorry I'm newbie so I don't know how to express it!
Here's how I loaded the table from earlier: stackoverflow.com/questions/76119023/…
Now I want after selecting each table one row.
After the selection is complete, the data table will be displayed from another sql database table

Comment: It could very well be me that is stupid... But I can't understand the importance of "from another sql database" unless you are fetching something, and how the users choices are relevant if you already have fetched it - unless its just a matter of filtering something you have already fetched and displaying it.

Comment: It's my fault because I don't know how to express it. I've updated the image above to describe the problem I'm having.

Comment: I have updated the question for you to see. Thank you very much !