# How to call Ajax on condition

Tags: jquery, ajax, database, datatable

I have a varible voyagekey. When I click on a row in the table, there will be a voyagekey of that ship.
[image]

Based on the value of that voyage key, how can the ajax call
display only the data lines that contain the voyage key variable? My Ajax call code currently only loads the datatable.

The variable to save when I need to find a suitable ship is voyagekey, and the field in the datatable I want to upload is VoyageKey.

```
$('#Form1, #Form2, #Form3').find('tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
  var vesselName = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
  var groupvoyage = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text();

  console.log('vesselName:', vesselName);
  console.log('voyagekey:', voyagekey);
  // Gán giá trị cho trường input
  $('#chooseVessel').val(vesselName);
  $('#chooseVoyage').val(groupvoyage);

  

  let me = $(this);
  // select me
  me.toggleClass('selected');
if (me.hasClass('selected')) {
  me.css('background-color', '#4987a2');
} else {
  me.css('background-color', '');
}

me.parent().find('.selected').not(me).removeClass('selected').css('background-color', '');

  // if three rows are selected, then do something
  // (there can only be one row in each table that is selected)
  if ($('.selected').length === 3) {

// Gọi ajax để load dữ liệu dựa trên voyagekey
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/Tally/Tally/get',
  data: { voyagekey: voyagekey },
success: function(result) {
 // Xử lý dữ liệu nhận được và hiển thị lên bảng ContentTable
 var data = result.data;
  if (data.length === 1) {
    data[0].STT = 1;
  } else {
    // Duyệt qua từng hàng và cập nhật STT
    $.each(data, function(index, row) {
      row.STT = index + 1;
    });
  }
      table.clear().draw();
      table.clear().rows.add(result.data).draw();
//      table.show();
         
},
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
});
        }
      });
```

The form table and datatable both have a voyagekey field, each ship name will have its own voyagekey field containing that ship's name. I want when I click on a ship's name, I only call ajax to the data table of the fields that have the same voyagekey. The first image shown is the voyagekey of the formtable. I saved to variable to compare with voyagekey in database.
These are voyagekeys saved to the variable.
[image]
Here is the list of ships to filter
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what your _specific_ problem is. I guess this is a follow-up to your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76169225/12567365). You ask "_how can the ajax call display only the data lines that contain the voyage key variable?_" I am not sure what you are specifically asking - but if you are successfully sending the correct value to the server using `data: { voyagekey: voyagekey }`, then it is the job of your server code to use that value to filter the data it returns as its response to the Ajax request. None of that code is shown in your question.

Comment: The title of your question is "How to call Ajax on condition" - but your code is already doing this. At least, it looks as if it is. So, maybe the title is also misleading?

Comment: I think your code is fine. Your server needs to filter and return the data based on voyagekey provided through your ajax : data: { voyagekey: voyagekey },

Comment: Thanks everyone, maybe my question is a bit confusing. I'm sorry and sorry about that. I've updated the post to make the question a bit clearer. Hope you can help.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you need to filter the result data of your ajax call, based on filter criteria?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to add `WHERE : VoyageKey` to the query on the `Modal` file. This helped me to filter the `VoyageKey` field data to match the `voyagekey` array in my `View` file.